# SELECT in the WHERE LIKE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, sql-like

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `test2`
WHERE text LIKE (SELECT concat(startswith,"%") from test1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
```

Essentially I want to pick one row from the test1 table, and then find all the records from the test2 table that start with the characters from the **startswith** column in test1.

But this query doesn't do that. Where am I going wrong?

Here the tables in questing

```
SELECT * FROM `test1`

startswith
==========
aaa 
bbb 
ccc 

SELECT * FROM `test2`

text
====
aaa3k123k12312p03edwqeq 
aaa12313fwefrwerw   
aaafwre3we4232  
bbb123123rwqe12e1
```

Comment: SImply remove ORDER BY and LIMIT from the subquery?

Comment: @jarlh, if I do that, I get "Subquery returns more than 1 row" error.

Comment: Of course... Do a JOIN intead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use subselect in join like this

```
select t2.* from test2 as t2 join (SELECT RAND() as rand, startswith from test1 ORDER BY rand LIMIT 1) as t1 where t2.txt like CONCAT(t1.startswith,"%");
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the subquery, and `JOIN`:

```
SELECT text
FROM `test2`
JOIN (select startswith from test1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) t1
    ON text LIKE concat(startswith,"%")
```

Comment: this will just return all the rows from test2 that start with *any* of the startwith in test1. I want to pick one startwith randomly from test1 table.

Comment: This gives me the error: "Every derived table must have its own alias". See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=90a511d069b6d86fb718722c49de86c2

Comment: I see, some products want that, others don't. Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't give you the results you expect (for example, with your sample data sometimes it returns values starting with both `aaa` and `bbb`, or you may not get all the values starting with `aaa`) is that the `WHERE` condition is evaluated **for each row** of test2. That means that for each row in test2, a **new, random** value is compared against, this can lead (potentially) to matching all lines, or none, even if all values in `test1` are the start of a value in `test2`.

The way around this is to create a derived table from your subquery - so that it only gets evaluated **once** - and then `JOIN` that to `test2` using the `LIKE` comparison you are using:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM (SELECT startswith FROM test1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) t1
JOIN test2 t2 ON t2.text LIKE CONCAT(t1.startswith, '%')
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=a0392ac7269002160a485ecae2e0f0f3)

Note that if `startswith` is "ccc", you will get no results in the output for your sample data.

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems to be like this `SELECT * FROM test2WHERE text LIKE ==========%` without quotations.
If you put a temporary data on your query would it still get the results?
Something like

```
SELECT * FROM `test2`
WHERE text LIKE aaa%  -->> will not run, should have quotations
```

and this

```
SELECT * FROM `test2`
WHERE text LIKE 'aaa%'
```

To complete your code

```
SELECT * FROM `test2`
WHERE text LIKE Concat((SELECT startswith from test1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1), "%")
```

Comment: This will not produce the results that I mentioned in the question. See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=10354e642237e1ae5adcc1769864b01c